# In a short bibliography, how to not have the references numbered?

Tags: bibliographies

I was looking at [this page](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3907111) for how to set up a short bibliography in LaTeX.  When I write

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\em Readings compiled for History
  21.479.}  1991.

\bibitem{impj}  The Japan Reader {\em Imperial Japan 1800-1945} 1973:
  Random House, N.Y.

\bibitem{norman} E. H. Norman {\em Japan's emergence as a modern
  state} 1940: International Secretariat, Institute of Pacific
  Relations.

\bibitem{fo} Bob Tadashi Wakabayashi {\em Anti-Foreignism and Western
  Learning in Early-Modern Japan} 1986: Harvard University Press.

\end{thebibliography}
```

It compiles like this:

[image]

I was wondering how I might be able to modify this so that the numbers are not displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\em Readings compiled for History
  21.479.}  1991.

\bibitem{impj}  The Japan Reader {\em Imperial Japan 1800-1945} 1973:
  Random House, N.Y.

\bibitem{norman} E. H. Norman {\em Japan's emergence as a modern
  state} 1940: International Secretariat, Institute of Pacific
  Relations.

\bibitem{fo} Bob Tadashi Wakabayashi {\em Anti-Foreignism and Western
  Learning in Early-Modern Japan} 1986: Harvard University Press.

\end{thebibliography}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine the `thebibliography`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\section*{\refname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
  \list{}%
       {\leftmargin0pt
        \@openbib@code
        \usecounter{enumiv}}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m}
 {\def\@noitemerr
   {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist}
\makeatother
```

Please see that commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are needed because the code uses `@`.

With the complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\section*{\refname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
  \list{}%
       {\leftmargin0pt
        \@openbib@code
        \usecounter{enumiv}}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m}
 {\def\@noitemerr
   {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\em Readings compiled for History
  21.479.}  1991.

\bibitem{impj}  The Japan Reader {\em Imperial Japan 1800-1945} 1973:
  Random House, N.Y.

\bibitem{norman} E. H. Norman {\em Japan's emergence as a modern
  state} 1940: International Secretariat, Institute of Pacific
  Relations.

\bibitem{fo} Bob Tadashi Wakabayashi {\em Anti-Foreignism and Western
  Learning in Early-Modern Japan} 1986: Harvard University Press.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

you get:

[image]